# iOS navigation bar overlapping top of UIImageView when auto resizing

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

The layout for my DetailView is as follows:

[image]

You can see I placed the UIImageView immediately below the black navigation bar.

I want the width of the image to fill the screen if the device is in portrait or landscape.

On IB, the UIImageView is "Aspect Fill" and has a custom height constraint of >=240.

Two problems are arising:

- first, although the UIImageView width fills the screen the vertical dimension is not resizing automatically
- second, images with height > 240 only grow vertically **under** the navigation bar

Any suggestions how to fix this? Glad to post code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, instead of using auto resizing, my idea is to set frame for your UIImageView like the following

In - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self checkOrientation];
}
```

and in checkOrientation

```
- (void)checkOrientation
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)) {
        // set imageview frame to fit what you need
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        // set imageview frame to fit what you need
    }
}
```

hope it at least help you a bit, thanks.